# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n-k^2}}$

Tags: limits

Find  this follow limit
$$I=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n-k^2}}$$

since
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2}}$$
I guess  we have
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(k/n)^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

But I can't prove  follow is true
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(k/n)^2}}$$
I have only prove 
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2}}$$
Thank you

Comment: Your last integral is arcsin x from 0 to 1 and I think you get $\pi /2$ not 1 .  However I don't undertand how you got to the square root with 2 terms from the square root with 3 terms.

Comment: @BettyMock: I'm sure math110 means by "I guess we have ..." that the claim "$I = \dots$" in the line immediately following is a guess.  It's a reasonable guess because when $n$ is very large, the $\frac1n$ term looks like it doesn't contribute.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd sounds like a reasonable interpretation.  Seems like the final answer should have a k in it.

Comment: I am confused about the choice of notation. Given, a sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ we denote the sum of the first $n$ terms as:\begin{equation}S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\end{equation} In your question you have the stuff you are summing depending on $n$ ... shouldn't it just depend on $k$?

Answer (score 4):

The difference term-wise is 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{ \sqrt {1+({\frac{k}{n}})^2}} - \frac{1}{ \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{n} - {(\frac{k}{n}})^2}}&= \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{    \sqrt {1+({\frac{k}{n}})^2}\cdot  \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{n} - ({\frac{k}{n}})^2}  ( \sqrt {1+({\frac{k}{n}})^2}+  \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{n} - ({\frac{k}{n}})^2})  }  \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{   \sqrt {1+({\frac{k}{n}})^2}\cdot  \sqrt {1- ({\frac{k}{n}})^2}  ( \sqrt {1+({\frac{k}{n}})^2}+  \sqrt {1  - ({\frac{k}{n}})^2})     }
\end{align}

Therefore when we take the difference of the sums we get one extra $\frac{1}{n}$ and the other quantity converges to an integral thus the result is zero which proves your claim.

$$ 0 \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{  \sqrt{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}  \sqrt { (1-x^2)   }+\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}\rm{d}x=0$$

Answer (score 3):

For any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, you  can write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon-(k/n)^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1/n)-(k/n)^2}}$ for $n>n_0.$
This will converge to $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon-x^2}}dx.$$
Therefore, 
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon-x^2}}dx \le \lim I \le \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx,$$
 but $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Nice and simple. Allows to replace $+n$ in $n^2+n-k^2$ by any $+x_n$ if $x_n\geqslant0$ and $x_n=o(n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it can be generalize in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You have already establised that $I \leq \frac\pi2$.

If you instead divide numerator and denominator by $n+1$ rather than $n$ you get:

$$ I = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac1{n+1} - \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^2}} $$

Letting $m = n+1$, and adding and subtracting the $0$th summand this is:

$$ \begin{aligned} I 
 & = \lim_{m\to \infty} \left( \frac1m \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac1m - \left(\frac k m\right)^2}} - \frac1m \frac1{\sqrt{1 - \frac1m - \left(\frac 0m\right)^2}} \right) \\ 
 & = \lim_{m\to \infty} \left( \frac1m \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac1m - \left(\frac k m\right)^2}} - \frac1m \frac1{\sqrt{1 - \frac1m }} \right) \\
 & = \lim_{m\to \infty} \left( \frac1m \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac1m - \left(\frac k m\right)^2}}\right) - \lim_{m\to \infty} \left(\frac1m \frac1{\sqrt{1 - \frac1m }} \right) 
\end{aligned} $$

The second limit is $0$.  The first limit is bounded below by the integral $\frac\pi2$ that you found, just as in your limit you found it was bounded above.  Thus $\frac\pi2 \leq I \leq \frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Let's check what Euler-Maclaurin says:
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{n^{2} + n - k^{2}}}}={1 \over \root{n}} +
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over \root{n^{2} + n - k^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over \root{n}} + \overbrace{\int_{0}^{n}{\dd k \over \root{n^{2} + n - k^{2}}}}^{\ds{\arcsin\pars{n \over\root{n^{2} + n}}}}
-
\half\pars{{1 \over \root{n^{2} + n}} + {1 \over \root{n}}}
+ {1 \over 12}\,{1 \over \root{n}}\\[3mm]&
- {1 \over 720}\pars{{15 \over \root{n}} + {9 \over n\root{n}}} + \cdots
\color{#0000ff}{\large\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} {\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

It seems $\pi/2$ is the correct result but the convergence, in the numerical side, is very slow. Even with $n = 10^{8}$, the difference respect of $\pi/2$ is $\approx -0.00135758$.

Comment: -1. Unless one explains what is in the $+\cdots$, this is not a proof in the mathematical sense of the term (as was already explained to you several times).